# Is JSF2 allows Component class and facelet xhtml together?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

Is it possible to use both composite component facelet (xhtml, cc.attrs and etc. ) and component class ( extended from UIComponent) in one component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Facelets composite components in JSF UI components, but you can use (custom) JSF UI components in Facelets composite components.

Composite components are a Facelets feature, not a JSF feature. The relation between JSF and Facelets is that Facelets is a view technology which is designed with JSF in mind. It's in essence the successor of JSP and by default included/supported since JSF 2.0.

Comment: I know the things you are write above, but I still don't understand how to use it. I think that abbreviations "cc.attrs" and "cc.clientId" assume that there is some java class for component, behind the scene. I want to know, if it is possible to override/extend it in such way that "cc.myFunc" will be available?

Comment: Thank you. However it are not good news. One of the important features of using facelts together with JSF2 is that the developer do less configuration work. The things that you wrote mean that if I want complicated component I still need to create component class, renderer class and taglib. Ohhh.

Comment: That's the caveat if you need a (over)complicated component.